# Flask send image with curl as json payload

Tags: python, api, flask, curl, file-upload

I have a simple flask API with file upload to send an image:

```
from flask import request
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    f = request.files['image']
    print(f.content_type)
    print(f.filename)
    # do something with the file
    # f.read() 
return("Done")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

When I send an image using `curl`'s `-F` option, I can access the file:
`curl -XPOST localhost:5000 -F "image=@img.jpg"`

But how can I send an image as a payload in a json file with the `-d` option? If I encode the image using `base64`, put the string into a json file and send it with the `-d` option, it cannot find my image: `KeyError: 'image'`
I tried with different content types:

`curl -XPOST localhost:5000 -d @img.json --header "Content-Type: application/json"`

`curl -XPOST localhost:5000 -d @img.json --header "Content-Type: image/jpeg"`

My `image.json` looks something like this:

`{"image":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAS..."}`

(with the complete string instead of `...`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending data as JSON payload, you will have to use `request.json` to access them. [Flask docs for files attribute](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.files) state, that this attribute is non-empty when `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. `curl` will set `multipart/form-data` header implicitly when you use `-F` option.

But for json data you have to set `--header "Content-Type: application/json"` as you have in you example. However, you have to check [request.mimetype](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.mimetype) on the server side. Based on that check, you will either use `files` or `json` attribute. Here is the example how to handle those 2 cases:

```
from flask import request
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.mimetype == 'multipart/form-data':
        f = request.files['image']
        print(f.content_type)
        print(f.filename)
        # do something with the file
        # f.read() 
    else if request.mimetype == 'application/json':
        f = request.json['image']
        print(f)
        # decode f from Base64
    else:
        # handle other mimetypes or return that selected mimetype is not supported 
        print('Unsupported content-type')
  
    return("Done")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

The `curl` command you used should be handled correctly:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:5000 -d @img.json --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```